# Draw from the top or draw from the bottom?

Tags: filament

From day one I've always had my spool so that filament comes off "the top", but recently I wondered if it mattered, or there were any advantages/disadvantages to which side of the spool the filament came from. I did find [this](https://forum.prusa3d.com/forum/original-prusa-i3-mk3s-mk3-general-discussion-announcements-and-releases/should-filament-spools-feed-over-the-top-or-from-under-the-bottom/), but it proved inconclusive. So, does it matter which side of the spool the filament comes from. Are their any pros/cons to either side? Or is this just a matter of personal preference?

Comment: This is completely setup-dependent. Post a photo.

Answer (score 1):

It just depends on your set-up. Ideally, you don't want to have the filament entering the extruder at too great of an angle, so depending on where your extruder is and how filament is fed into it will determine which way your spool should go.

Answer (score 1):

As Echo has said, it's not really that big of a deal. I usually just stick to having the filament coming over the spool and I've rarely seen it another way. It's what made sense to me with the fact I have a stand for the spools attached to the frame of the printer along the top. It's really just personal preference.